# razor : creating pinterest string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to create a pinterest pin it button.
Below is the code:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.name%2Fproduct%2F@Model.ProductDetails.URLName&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.name%2Fproduct%2F@Model.ProductDetails.Image&description=@Model.ProductDetails.ProductDescription" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

As you see there are three variables:

```
url : http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.name%2Fproduct%2F@Model.ProductDetails.URLName

media: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.name%2Fproduct%2F@Model.ProductDetails.Image

description: @Model.ProductDetails.ProductDescription
```

In all three variables some data is coming from ViewModel using @Model

But only `@Model.ProductDetails.ProductDescription` is working
And the other two are not working maybe because they are part of a bigger string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The razor parser thinks that the first two values are email addresses or similar and so leaves them as plain text. In order to inform the parser that they should be evaluated you need to use an Explicit Expression, eg `@(Model.Property)`, so your variables would be:

```
url : http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.name%2Fproduct%2F@(Model.ProductDetails.URLName)
media: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.name%2Fproduct%2F@(Model.ProductDetails.Image)
description: @(Model.ProductDetails.ProductDescription)
```

And your snippet would be:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.name%2Fproduct%2F@(Model.ProductDetails.URLName)&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.name%2Fproduct%2F@(Model.ProductDetails.Image)&description=@(Model.ProductDetails.ProductDescription)" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

I generally keep [Phil Haack's Razor Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) guide bookmarked!

Comment: You can also use @Url.Encode to wrap the url, media & description properties.